# Python : storing class instance function in dict

Tags: python, python-3.4

I try to write a ChatBot program that will respond to each user differently.
So I implement like this: When there is a new user, ask the bot to do something and my bot needs to ask user back for more information and wait for the response message, my code will register a dict with a key of user_id and value of call_back function of class User like example code below.

```
class User:
    api_dict = {}
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id

    def ask_username(self,chat_env):
        chat_env.send_msg(self.user_id,"Please enter your username")
        api_dict[self.user_id] = self.ask_birth_date

    def ask_birth_date(self,message,chat_env)
        chat_env.send_msg(self.user_id,"Mr. {} what is your birth date".format(message))
        # do some thing            
def hook_function(user_id,message,chat_env)
    if is_first_hook(user_id):
        user = User(user_id)
        user.ask_username()
    else:
        User.api_dict[user_id](message,chat_env)
```

But it was not working as python threw an error that it didn't receive `chat_env` parameter in `ask_birth_date()` in which I think `self` wasn't passed to the function.
So is there any way to make `self` still attach with `ask_birth_date()`?

Comment: You did not set `self.user_id` in `__init__`, you only aim to fetch it.

Comment: Thank you for your note, now I have edited my question. actually this code is just an example.

Comment: you could potentially implement a "`get_chat_env()`" function

Comment: `User.api_dict` is a call to a class attribute - do you mean `User().api_dict` ?

Comment: For "class instant function" i means for ask_birth_date() and I actually means User.api_dict as class attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you must be storing all the instances of `User` somewhere to be able to call `ask_username` when a connection is first made. Therefore you can transform `api_dict` into a [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

```
Users = {}  # I'm guessing you already have this!

class User:
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id

    def ask_username(self, chat_env):
        chat_env.send_msg(self.user_id, "Please enter your username")
        self.current = self.ask_birth_date

    def ask_next_question(self, message, chat_env)
        self.current(message, chat_env)

    def ask_birth_date(self, message, chat_env)
        chat_env.send_msg(self.user_id, "Mr. {} what is your birth date".format(message))
        self.current = self.record_birth_date  # for example

# There must be code that does this already
def new_connection(user_id, chat_env):
    Users[user_id] = User(user_id)
    Users[user_id].ask_username(chat_env)

# I assume this is called for every message that arrives from a user
def hook_function(user_id, message, chat_env)
    Users[user_id].ask_next_question(message, chat_env)
```

**Update:**

Your hook function doesn't call `ask_username()` properly. That is why you are getting the error. That is why you should post all your code **and** the whole of the stack trace!

This code should fix your call site:

```
def hook_function(user_id, message, chat_env)
    if is_first_hook(user_id):
        user = User(user_id)
        user.ask_username(chat_env)  # add param here!
        # btw the user instance here is thrown away!
    else:
        User.api_dict[user_id](message, chat_env)
```

If the above fixes your problems, then that means that the `User` class is unnecessary. You could just have `api_dict` as a global and the methods can become free functions.

Your code can be reduced to this:

```
api_dict = {}

def ask_username(chat_env, user_id):
    chat_env.send_msg(user_id, "Please enter your username")
    api_dict[user_id] = ask_birth_date

def ask_birth_date(chat_env, user_id, message)
    chat_env.send_msg(user_id, "Mr. {} what is your birth date".format(message))
    # do some thing            

def hook_function(user_id, message, chat_env)
    if is_first_hook(user_id):
        ask_username(chat_env, user_id)
    else:
        api_dict[user_id](chat_env, user_id, message)
```

Comment: yeah, I actually store user some where but I didn't use it to call directly as I need to keep the sequence of asking or state of user as hook function. 
However, thank you by the way, I got some Idea to change my design